# Can you conditionally assign a type based on a boolean value?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I asked myself the question in the title while dealing with this issue: I have function `getResponse` from a library which either returns `{ a: number }` if it's an Android phone or `{ b: number }` if it's an iOS phone.

I had this code and the assignment to `value` here gives me a type error:

```
const response = getResponse();

const value = isAndroid ? response.a : response.b;
```

I solved the issue with a type guard by creating a type predicate `isAndroidResponse`

```
const isAndroidResponse = (
  response: { a: number } | { b: number }
): response is { a: number } => {
  return isAndroid; // 'response' parameter not used!
};
```

and using it as follows:

```
const response = getResponse();

let value;
if (isAndroidResponse(response)) {
  value = response.a;
} else {
  value = response.b;
}
```

However, I have two issues with this solution which make me doubt whether it really is a "good" solution for my problem:

1. In the type predicate I'm not using the passed `response` variable.
2. It is a lot of code! I would love to have much less code, by perhaps just do something along these lines (which is not correct TS code):

   ```
   type ResponseT = isAndroid ? { a: number } : { b: number };

   const response = getResponse();

   const value = isAndroid ? response.a : response.b;
   ```

This brings me to my **follow-up question**: Is my usage of a type predicate a feasible solution or am I misusing it in this case?

I created [this TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEFQIwexgbApgQwHagG7PgV0aAWlEQEsAXAC0QCdQzq9QZaAzbAZ0QDpQBlRMnRh0G%20FszoUS7YgA9kAWwAOSLgFgAUAGMYqdoOnhUAE2owSx0AF4ReANyaQoAGI5UWsiV2gA7uQqgxiQsLDSIqILUiOw48GQyUMiclt4qyGTi1AqgABQkAPK8mOw8RqbmxgCUmjp6ggDmAgBK0Uq6nNa5ldYAfKCGJmYWoAD8uQDeoMgAXKAAjACsoAC%203bM5k1CziyuVDhqOYAAqAJ5K%20EpRQVrpiDXtBuxlQ8Yt7G16%20DY5mqCgUe92ohZpMZqBUDgFFAaCtQAAfUCbWYQqEw5aaSqzAEfDrSRFTZGQ6G0Za9RG-f4CHDUdADcoWOygJwAcmxQOZoCUyGoigEMNQMEEOGSAEJNMt9vc6pTAZ9Oo0yG8cYgcntNJokIIsLhEPsnKdzqB6jhucZNMFcnSXkqgTk2Z9Kt1xhTtYwbPbOFxkPtSYh4B1nRo-q6vjLlVwoD7NEA) for the described example.

Comment: Are you going to *compile* the code twice, once for `true` and once for `false`?

Comment: Also, your [mcve] might be a little *too* minimal, since my inclination here would be to inspect `response` and not worry about `isAndroid` anymore, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAVXQW).  If you go further and make the response type of `getResponse()` a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) with an `isAndroid` discriminant property like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpDrpm), then you could just check the discriminant.

Comment: @jcalz The getResponse function comes from a third-party React Native lib. It will return a different response object dependent on the platform (iOS vs. Android) which is determined at runtime. `isAndroid` can give me this information outside of the lib.

Your first solution to inspect `response` directly indeed is an option - however, that code does not "explain" the platform distinction. Your second option (discriminated union) is not possible because I can't amend the third-party lib. Would wrapping a discriminant property around the given response be a feasible approach?

Comment: Yeah, you could either [wrap or merge](https://tsplay.dev/w11eOw) the discriminant property to get that behavior.  I think your original method of using a type guard function is probably fine but it's definitely strange for it not to depend on the value being passed in... it's essentially a distributed discriminated union; your `isAndroid` boolean floats out there seemingly unrelated to the response.  The explicit wrapped/merged discriminated union might be a little less confusing and easier to support.  If either of the above linked solutions helps I'm happy to write it up.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks! A wrap or merge is only minimally less verbose compared to my type guard function, but since you say it's less confusing, I'll go for that. I personally prefer the merge over the wrap since it doesn't give me `response.response.a` etc. 
Thanks for compiling an answer! In your answer, could you perhaps also explain what you mean by "distributed" as you used it in "distributed discriminated union"?

Comment: I will do so, but it's a term I just made up.  Maybe "nonlocal" is a better term.  But I will explain in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conceptually, you have a boolean value `isAndroid` which acts as a *discriminant* for the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) that comes out of `getResponse()`.  It means that the return type of `getResponse()` is like a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), but one where the discriminant property is floating disconnected from the return value itself.  I'll call this a "nonlocal discriminated union" for want of a standard term.

TypeScript really isn't set up to understand nonlocal discriminated unions, so you will need to work around it in some way.

---

If you really care about minimizing excess code, the best you can do is to use some [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to just tell the compiler what it can't verify by itself:

```
const response = getResponse();
const value = isAndroid ? 
  (response as AndroidResponse).a : 
  (response as IOSResponse).b;
```

This isn't type safe, (e.g., nothing stops you from changing the test from `isAndroid` to `!isAndroid`) but neither is the implementation of your `isAndroidResponse()` [user-defined type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), nor is any solution that defines `isAndroid` prior to the call to `getResponse()`.

If you are only writing `getResponse()` once or twice in your code, I would recommend type assertions.

---

If you are going to write `getResponse()` many places in your code, then maybe you do want to refactor so that the unsafe part is encapsulated in a single function, like `isAndroidResponse()`.

If you do want to do this, my opinion (and this is just an opinion) is that your `isAndroidResponse()` implementation is fine.  It might surprise people since it seems weird that you'd be able to do anything without inspecting the `response` argument.  But if you comment it, that might be okay.

---

Another approach is to make the nonlocal discriminated union into a true discriminated union, by adding `isAndroid` as a discriminant property of the response:

```
// definitions
type Response =
    ({ isAndroid: true } & AndroidResponse) |
    ({ isAndroid: false } & IOSResponse)
const getResponseʹ = () =>
    Object.assign(getResponse(), { isAndroid }) as Response

// usage
const response = getResponseʹ();
const value = response.isAndroid ? response.a : response.b;
```

The unsafe code is confined to the implementation of `getResponseʹ()` (since we had to assert the return type), but now you can forget about the original `isAndroid` flag and instead leverage the support the language has for discriminated unions.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAlgzgggOwCYCcD2UkQLwQLICGYAFgHQoHJoC2AFAJQQA8EADKQKwDcAsAFBQEYECgBmBAMYgIiVBiQAlEDAAOaBDGkBvfhD0QCALggIArtQBGI-gF9+g4WMnSAkgHkAyktXrNEHXz6EBbGZpbWfHZ8-BK+kADm4N5qGtK4DMay6JjJvtIAPhDuXsopftgAfLr6sFnyEAD8ELRaBsYAjBwQNozGLcEdXT280aMIBNSlzhBuKFDx-vxLgfqxGpC1yNmKpXk4zdVBeii7qZlb8rmpEIXFV5qHEPTGJz7XsDIXOaflFYsrRwgJzAphQCGg8C+SC4EAA9LCIAByV5lECIiAqAgUSaOExoSCmTRIACEjxsI0eaxgkBRe1wiTA9xADBGQSpkAAbgRgKY0hC6t83ppaLTUowmqLNKQCBAXj8QKQLBTIstluNJqppnAYJoUGAoL5-my4kD5fsGUyWZSTVyeXzNnJMI1HkERWaCDBPo6dkKQPRpbKXfo3b6DJ67vL-UrbKqxhMplIIAARWASObUQREEBIACqCAN4ICyyCYAAnippEycEG9P0HdtjGAULzuhAAGRe7ZMxj5GvNVr1+TGcTAPw2dtFTzd4urE0W+WATqB9gwcFUAUc3BYAFYgCRgaU6+YIWjz30MAA0-n5UO6jA9ECZM707NNofpSUXVvXL9tLdwkoVQcnQleUAzlX1FRGKJY3VBNpDgYAoA9bMAGF1CQKB9XUAB1dAEHiJMQArZAQAQCRS1mJARH+a11lfVFzQ-M96FZWc6KArBcAAIgILjoHBADWOfG1uT-a9vUaei8jAqTUkVJ84QAKggAA5NwABUIAANTgAAZFwkwgWjqXEhtZL8D4BR9BjcEIEhyEoJAaBXFh2G4YyaTNd9GXlL9jTo397UhCSQIgmVwNReT10U2FlhsIA)

Comment: Was first wondering why the type cast `as Response` in the last example is necessary but then realized that it is because TypeScript can't know that the nonlocal boolean value `isAndroid` determines the structure of the discriminant union.

Btw: Thanks for this great answer @jcalz which helped me learn a lot about TypeScript (like so many of your other TS related answers)! :-)

Comment: Right, exactly.  If the compiler had any idea that `isAndroid` was correlated to the return value of `getResponse()`, there wouldn't be a problem in the first place.  No matter what you do here, you'll need to *tell* the compiler about the correlation. This involves some unsafe code *somewhere*, since when you tell the compiler about something like this, it'll just believe you even if you're lying or mistaken.  Type assertions, function overload implementations, user-defined type guard function implementations, and assertion function implementations are all unsafe in this way.